# How to GroupBy in Query Laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to grouping `table_name` in my data using laravel query builder. But when i run it, the result still not grouping.
This is my data :

[image]

And this is my query to do this:

```
$data['list_module'] = DB::table('roles as a')
                         ->leftJoin('permission_role as b', 'a.id', 'b.role_id')
                         ->leftJoin('permissions as c', 'b.permission_id', 'c.id')
                         ->where('a.id', $id)
                         ->select('c.key','c.table_name')
                         ->groupBy('c.key', 'c.table_name')
                         ->orderBy('c.table_name', 'DESC')
                         ->get();
```

Comment: It has already grouped, it is grouped by `key` and `tablename`.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is used in sql to allow for aggregate queries on sets of data. You don't seem to have any such queries here. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It has already grouped, it is grouped by `key` and `table_name`.

If you want to group by only `table_name`, Try this:

```php
$data['list_module'] = DB::table('roles as a')
                         ->leftJoin('permission_role as b', 'a.id', 'b.role_id')
                         ->leftJoin('permissions as c', 'b.permission_id', 'c.id')
                         ->where('a.id', $id)
                         ->select('c.key','c.table_name')
                         ->groupBy('c.table_name')
                         ->orderBy('c.table_name', 'DESC')
                         ->get();
```

If you set sql_mode to [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), I think you need to use `any_value`:

```php
->select(\DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(c.key) AS key'),'c.table_name')
```

or in applications's database config file `config/database.php` mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode:

Comment: i have tried to change `groupBy('c.key', 'c.table_name')` to `groupBy('c.table_name')` but i got an error `c.id isn't in GROUP BY`.
I want the grouping result like this 
`table_name: "users", key: "delet" key: "edit", etc`

Comment: i'm sorry, i mean `c.key isn't in GroupBy`

Comment: @RahmatEffendi I think this error is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, you need to use `any_value` or set sql_mode without `only_full_group_by`.